# How can I add textures to my bars and wedges?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm drawing several bar and pie charts using [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) and [`matplotlib.pyplot.pie()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie). In both functions, I can change the colors of the bars and wedges.

However, I need to print these charts in black and white. It would be much more useful to be able to put textures on the bars and wedges, similar to the [`Line2D`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) marker property which is available for drawing lines. Can I maybe fill the bars and wedges with these markers in a consistent way? Or is there any other way to achieve something like that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With `bar()`, you can directly use hatches (with some backends): http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hatch_demo.html:
[image: bar plot with hatches]

It works by adding the `hatch` argument to your call to `bar()`.

---

As for `pie()`, it does not have a `hatch` keyword. You can instead get the individual pie chart patches and add hatches to them: you get the patches with:

```
patches = pie(…)[0]  # The first element of the returned tuple are the pie slices
```

then you apply the hatches to each slice (patch):

```
patches[0].set_hatch('/')  # Pie slice #0 hatched.
```

(hatches list at https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_hatch).

And you apply the changes with:

```
pyplot.draw()
```

[image: Hatched pie chart]]

Comment: Awesome! I would have never found that out so fast on my own. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 54):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

patterns = [ "/" , "\\" , "|" , "-" , "+" , "x", "o", "O", ".", "*" ]

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
for i in range(len(patterns)):
    ax1.bar(i, 3, color='red', edgecolor='black', hatch=patterns[i])


plt.show()
```

[image]

It's in the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_hatch).

Okay - so to texture a piechart, you need to do this:

if you look [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=pie#matplotlib.pyplot.pie):

```
Return value:
If autopct is None, return the tuple (patches, texts):

patches is a sequence of matplotlib.patches.Wedge instances
texts is a list of the label matplotlib.text.Text instances.
```

so then we look at the [Wedges](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Wedge) page, and see that it has a set_hatch() method.

so we just need to add a few lines to the piechart demo and...

Example 1:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

patterns = [ "/" , "\\" , "|" , "-" , "+" , "x", "o", "O", ".", "*" ]

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
for i in range(len(patterns)):
    ax1.bar(i, 3, color='red', edgecolor='black', hatch=patterns[i])


plt.show()
```

Example 2:

```
"""
Make a pie chart - see
http://matplotlib.sf.net/matplotlib.pylab.html#-pie for the docstring.

This example shows a basic pie chart with labels optional features,
like autolabeling the percentage, offsetting a slice with "explode",
adding a shadow, and changing the starting angle.

"""

from pylab import *
import math
import numpy as np

patterns = [ "/" , "\\" , "|" , "-" , "+" , "x", "o", "O", ".", "*" ]


def little_pie(breakdown,location,size):
    breakdown = [0] + list(np.cumsum(breakdown)* 1.0 / sum(breakdown))
    for i in xrange(len(breakdown)-1):
        x = [0] + np.cos(np.linspace(2 * math.pi * breakdown[i], 2 * math.pi *    
                          breakdown[i+1], 20)).tolist()
        y = [0] + np.sin(np.linspace(2 * math.pi * breakdown[i], 2 * math.pi * 
                          breakdown[i+1], 20)).tolist()
        xy = zip(x,y)
        scatter( location[0], location[1], marker=(xy,0), s=size, facecolor=
               ['gold','yellow', 'orange', 'red','purple','indigo','violet'][i%7])

figure(1, figsize=(6,6))

little_pie([10,3,7],(1,1),600)
little_pie([10,27,4,8,4,5,6,17,33],(-1,1),800)

fracs = [10, 8, 7, 10]
explode=(0, 0, 0.1, 0)

piechart = pie(fracs, explode=explode, autopct='%1.1f%%')
for i in range(len(piechart[0])):
    piechart[0][i].set_hatch(patterns[(i)%len(patterns)])


show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. :) And how do I do this for pie wedges?

Comment: @PeterStahl - Sorry, i've never used pie charts. set_hatch is a method for the artist though, so you should be able to set it get getting the artist for each slice.

Comment: Thank you will. But since @EOL was the first one providing the solution, I accepted his answer. I gave you an upvote though. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yah i noticed. Pipped me at the post

Comment: @will: the hatching loop would be more simply written as `for wedge in piechart[0]: wedge.set_hatch(…)`.

Comment: @EOL i know, but i wanted it to choose a different pattern for each one. I guess i could have put a counter in there, but I like to be consistent

Comment: @EOL and i also guess i didn't realise i could have done `for wedge,hatch in zip(pichart[0],patterns):` which i guess would be best...

Comment: @will: I see what you mean, you're right. I like the `zip()` approach, but it would need to take into account the case of more than `len(patterns)` wedges: `for wedge, hatch in zip(piechart[0], itertools.cycle(patterns))`.

Comment: It's worth noting that repeating the hatch character increases the intensity of pattern as stated in [docs.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_hatch)

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_ribbon_box.html

which uses **matplotlib.image.BboxImage**

I believe this can resize a given image according to input data.