# How do I plot hatched bars using pandas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I am trying to achieve differentiation by hatch pattern instead of by (just) colour. How do I do it using pandas?

It's possible in matplotlib, by passing the `hatch` optional argument as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279344/how-can-i-add-textures-to-my-bars-and-wedges). I know I can also pass that option to a pandas `plot`, but I don't know how to tell it to use a different hatch pattern for each `DataFrame` column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df.plot(kind='bar', hatch='/');
```

[image]

For colours, there is the `colormap` option described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#colormaps). Is there something similar for hatching? Or can I maybe set it manually by modifying the `Axes` object returned by `plot`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Plot the grouped bars with `pandas.DataFrame.plot`, and then iterate through the bar patches, to add the hatches.

**Tested in `python 3.11.4`, `pandas 2.1.0`, `matplotlib 3.7.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

ax = df.plot(kind='bar', legend=False, figsize=(10, 6), rot=0, width=0.8)

bars = ax.patches
hatches = ''.join(h*len(df) for h in 'x/O.')

for bar, hatch in zip(bars, hatches):
    bar.set_hatch(hatch)

ax.legend(loc='lower center', ncol=4, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.15))
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, just the acceptable kind of hacky :) Now we just need to submit a patch like this to pandas.plot as `hatchmap=True` or something...

Comment: Rather than filtering `ax.get_children()`, it might be enough to simply access the bars as `ax.patches`.

Comment: Brilliant.  I adapted this approach to a df.plot.barh I have and it works perfectly.  I have 8 bar segments and hatched every other bar with `' / / / /'` (there are spaces for no pattern).  +1 for the question and the accepted answer.

Comment: How would this look for stacked area plots?

Comment: Better to do `hatches = [h for h in patterns for _ in range(len(df))]` because all hatches patterns don't have the same length (e.g. "xxx")

Answer (score 6):

This code allows you a little more freedom when defining the patterns, so you can have '//', etc.

```
bars = ax.patches
patterns =('-', '+', 'x','/','//','O','o','\\','\\\\')
hatches = [p for p in patterns for i in range(len(df))]
for bar, hatch in zip(bars, hatches):
    bar.set_hatch(hatch)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is plotting each column individually:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, 10, size=(5, 4)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
hatches = list('-*/o')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, c in enumerate(df.columns):
    ax.bar(x=df.index - 0.3 + 0.2*i, height=df[c], width=0.2, hatch=hatches[i], label=c)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Result]