# How can I set hatches when I'm using pandas.DataFrame.plot?

Tags: dataframe, plot, area, hatch

I'd like to plot 3 curves (using a dataframe) and I want them to have different hatches. Could you help me how to do that? I only found an option how to color the area under the curves (area plot). Thank you!

I tried to start based on this: [How do I plot hatched bars using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833404/how-do-i-plot-hatched-bars-using-pandas), but it wasn't successful. I also tried to put an argument hatch = ['/'] in the plot.area function, but it also didn't work.  Thank you!