# Can't build a non-stacked bar plot progressively, starting from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to build a bar plot with Pandas, matplotlib and Jupyter, where I'd like to place multiple series about the same index values one after another, without stacking. I've tried this:

```py
d = { 
  "shop": [ "London", "Berlin", "Paris" ],
  "sales-2020": [ 1000, 2344, 1233 ],
  "sales-2021": [ 355, 4003, 2344 ],
  "sales-2022": [ 2344, 2949, 3443 ]
}

colors = { "2020": "Blue", "2021": "Green", "2022": "Red" }

df = pd.DataFrame ( d, index = d [ "shop" ] )

ax = None
for yk in [ 2020, 2021, 2022 ]:
  yk = str ( yk )
  ax = df.plot.bar ( y = "sales-" + yk, label = yk, color = colors [ yk ], stacked = False, ax = ax )
```

But it gives me the wrong output, with the series always stacked and the first one not appearing as bars:

[image]

Yes, this is a XY question, I've tried to simplify a [more complex case](https://github.com/Rothamsted/graphdb-benchmarks/blob/master/results/querying-results.ipynb). Because I already have 9 series, I find it simpler to add them to the chart one at a time in a loop, not building everything in one go, as it was suggested. Also, I don't need to build a pivot table, for the data I have are already grouped.

Comment: `df.plot.bar(x='shop', stacked=True)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't want them as stacked

Comment: Then `stacked=False`?

Comment: It's a lot harder to bar plot one-by-one, bc you have to adjust the x position for each bar to get them side-by-side. Why not just do it one call?

Comment: @BigBen, why should I need to adjust the x? Doesn't it do auotmatically? I can't do it in one call, cause there are a lot of things to be set programmatically for each series and I have 9 series.

Comment: No, it's not adjusted automatically if you plot each series individually. That's why your output looks stacked. You should 1) rename the columns 2) pass `color=colors`.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks for your help,  but I wrote that doesn't work.

Comment: @BigBen, that's really weird, considering that if I do all of the above, but choosing a different plot type, it all works fine.

Comment: No it's not weird at all if you understand how bar plots work in matplotlib. Your x-data are categorical, but they need positioned according to a numeric value.

Comment: If you want to do this iteratively, then I suggest you use matplotlib directly. A sample is [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html).

Comment: No loops, just `df.plot.bar(x='shop', stacked=False)`, pandas will handle the `x`  shift for you.

Comment: @QuangHoang I've tried, but I also want to have different hatch patterns for the bars and can't do it in one go.

Comment: So many questions answer how to do that. [How do I plot hatched bars using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22833404/7758804).

Comment: Thank you @TrentonMcKinney, I don't know matplotlib much and basically, I didn't know how to search for this. About to post my solution.

Comment: **I didn't know how to search for this.** - this is always an issue when one starts programming. Also, ChatGPT, while not always correct, can put you on the correct path, but do not post ChatGPT answers here.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I stared using matplotlib recently, I started programming in late 1980s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself (thank you to those who voted for reopening the question):

Basically, matplotlib doesn't support a case like this out of the box. As [BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben) suggested (many thanks!), one needs to manipulate the x positions programmatically and place the bars in separated positions. I found a very good example [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py), and based on this, I've made [my own experiment](https://github.com/Rothamsted/graphdb-benchmarks/blob/master/results/test-multi-series-bar.ipynb), which I'll report here too:

```py
"""
Gets the x vector to locate the ibar (starts at 0) correctly, assuming you want to draw
nbar vertical bars and all the bars will take wbar_total units of width, where the bar groups
are spaced 1 unit.

Returns (the x vector, the single bar width, the next ibar )
"""
def bar_get_xs ( ibar, nbars, nlabels, wbar_total = 0.8 ):
  x = np.arange ( nlabels )
  # wbar_total = 0.8 # Because x = 0, 1, 2, you've a total of 1
  wbar = wbar_total / nbars 
  xi = x - wbar_total / 2  + wbar / 2 + ibar * wbar
  return (xi, wbar, ibar + 1)

"""
Sets the x ticks that match what was computed by get_bar_xs()
"""
def bar_set_xticks ( ax, nlabels ):
  x = np.arange ( nlabels )
  ax.set_xticks ( x )

######## data ########

d = { 
  "shop": [ "London", "Berlin", "Paris" ],
  "sales-2019": [ 200, 400, 800 ],
  "sales-2020": [ 100, 200, 400 ],
  "sales-2021": [ 2000, 1000, 500 ],
  "sales-2022": [ 50, 1500, 100 ]
}
years = [ 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022 ]

colors = { "2019": "Orange", "2020": "Blue", "2021": "Green", "2022": "Red" }

######## Chart ##########

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

nbars = len ( years )
nlabels = len ( d [ "shop" ] )
ibar = 0
for yk in years:
  yk = str ( yk )
  yid = "label-" + yk
  ylabel = yid
  xi, wbar, ibar = bar_get_xs ( ibar, nbars, nlabels )
  ax.bar ( xi, d [ "sales-" + yk ], yerr = 25, width = wbar, label = ylabel, 
    color = colors [ yk ], log = True )
    
ax.set_ylim ( ymin = 25 )
bar_set_xticks ( ax, nlabels )
ax.set_xticklabels ( d [ "shop" ] )
ax.legend()

# Finishing touches
ax.figure.set_size_inches ( 12, 7 )
ax.grid ( axis = "y", which = "both", linestyle='dotted' )
```

[image: bar chart with multiple series]

[Trenton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7758804/trenton-mckinney) suggested [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833404), where one builds the whole chart in one go and then manipulates the hatches separately. This might be an alternative approach, although I already had the code that add series progressively, in a loop.