# Venn Diagram with Textures using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, venn-diagram

I am to creating venn diagram using [matplotlib-venn](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib-venn). I am able to generate the graphs. Is there any possible way to create venn diagrams with textures like [matplotlib bar-chart/pie-chart with textures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14279510/9389643)?

Comment: Use `.set_hatch` on the patches created by the venn function.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
v = venn3(range(1,8))
p = v.get_patch_by_id('110')
p.set_hatch('\\\\')
p.set_edgecolor('black')
p.set_alpha(1.0)
```