# Gantt chart using plotly

Tags: python, plotly, gantt-chart

I am using plotly in Python 2.7 to produce Gantt charts like - [image: Gantt Chart]

But instead of filling the individual bars with color, I wish to fill them with different patterns so that it can be read even when printed in grey scale.

Is there a way to do that in Plotly? If not what other Python packages can do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is no option to do that.

Comment: Not even with some other python packages?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279344/how-can-i-add-textures-to-my-bars-and-wedges

Comment: Take a look at above link.