# Plot background customisation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using `matplotlib.pyplot` to display several data on one plot.

What I want to achieve is similar to what's shown in the following figure:

[image: Figure 1]

Where I've used combinations of `axvspan`s to generate the bands.

As you can see, the result is not very easily readable. One thing I would like to try is to use the same background color for the yellow and gray bands, but with different patterns, as in this figure (made with GIMP):

[image: Figure 2]

Where the white bands in the picture will have a similar pattern as the others but with, say, tilted orientation or inverted colors.

Is it possible to achieve that using Python?

Comment: I will never again assume to know what some people will find more or less readable.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen hahaha fair point. Indeed the second figure is way worse than the first one, but that's just due to my inability of using GIMP. I'd use better colors in my actual plot, I promise!

Comment: On a more serious note, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279344/how-can-i-add-textures-to-my-bars-and-wedges) might be a step in the right direction.